# Source of quotation from Buddhaghosa about Buddha being trackless

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, texts, dhammapada

[Radhakrishnan's edition of The Dhammapada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhammapada_(Radhakrishnan_translation)) provides the following quotation from Buddhaghosa as a commentary on Verse 179 (Chapt, 14, 1 Buddhavagga) where the Buddha is described as *apadam* trackless/signless:

> "The man who is possessed of even a single one of such conditions as
>   *raga*, attachment, &c., him ye can lead forward; but the Buddha has not even one condition or basis of renewed existence, and therefore by
>   what track will you lead this unconditioned Buddha?"

Could anyone tell me the source of this quotation and also provide me with the Pali?

Comment: Hi Adrian Hale and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have put together a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource section](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might find useful.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1996/254), and the comments underneath it, answer this question?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that doesn't help. I'm really looking for the source of the Buddhaghosa quote. Also I think apadam here means signless rather than trackless

Answer (score 3):

Radhakrishnan is not a wholly reliable guide to the Dhammapada. One must read him with care. The Pāḷi is

> *Kena padenāti yassa hi rāgapadādīsu ekapadampi atthi, taṃ tumhe tena
>   padena nessatha. Buddhassa pana ekapadampi natthi, taṃ apadaṃ buddhaṃ tumhe kena padena nessatha.* Dhammapada Aṭṭhakathā, 3.196.

It's from Buddhaghosa's commentary on the Dhammapada (Dhammapada Aṭṭhakathā). This section comments on the words "by what pada" (*kena padena*). My rough translation is:

> If he has even one from amongst the *padas* such as desire (*rāga*), then he can be led by that *pada*. But the Buddha has not even one of them, the Buddha is without a *pada*, there is no *pada* by which you can lead him.

The question then is what *pada* means here. If we read this along with Dhp 180 then it becomes clear that *pada* means desire etc (*rāgapadādi*). And it seems to me that "track" is a poor translation of *pada* here. It does not convey that in this context *pada* is referring to desire etc. I suggest that "sign" is somewhat better, but that even this is less than entirely satisfactory. Only the context can help us in this case.

In what sense craving is a "path" or a "track" or even a "sign" is moot. But then these verses are rather esoteric and a simple answer might be misleading anyway.